# Can we compute the magnitude of the stress caused by sound waves on a wall?

Tags: waves, acoustics

As a follow up to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/37823/why-cant-light-pass-through-walls-but-sound-can), Could we *really* compute the magnitude of the stress caused by sound waves on a wall? If so, How do we do that?

Comment: I think of the term _compute_ to mean 'calculate', i.e., 'make a theoretical estimate of the stress caused by sound waves.'  Is that what you mean in your question?  Or do you wish to know if you can _measure_ the stress? I feel like the answer would be quite a bit different based on that distinction.